# Allow outbound container networking through vpnkit

Tags: docker, iptables, moby, linuxkit

I have a linuxkit built VM here with a custom container `service` that I am trying to run.

```
services:
  ...

  - name: net-manager
    image: aemengo/net-manager:6bcc223a83e8a303a004bc6f6e383a54a3d19c55-amd64
    net: host
    capabilities:
      - all
    binds:
      - /usr/bin/vpnkit-expose-port:/usr/bin/vpnkit-expose-port # userland proxy
      - /usr/bin/vpnkit-iptables-wrapper:/usr/bin/iptables # iptables wrapper
      - /var/vpnkit:/port # vpnkit control 9p mount
      - /var/run:/var/run
    command:
      - sleep
      - 1d
```

With a base image of Alpine, the point of the `net-manager` service is to allow public internet connectivity to virtual ethernet adapters that I am spinning up on the `host: net` namespace. My current attempt is the following (inside the container):

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
$ /usr/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Just like you would do with a VM that wasn't utilizing vpnkit, but there doesn't seem to be any noticeable effect from doing this. For example, `nc -v google.com` is still failing. What am I missing? vpnkit is mounted and forwarded as the example here instructs to do:

https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/blob/master/examples/docker-for-mac.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was this line here:

```
binds:
...

/usr/bin/vpnkit-iptables-wrapper:/usr/bin/iptables
```

By overriding what the iptables executable was to the one provided by docker, things were misbehaving even though the commands reported no issue. It must be used for something swarm specific, as was mentioned in their docs.

The fix was to remove that binding and run the iptables that was provided in the container